# Python: running tally of iterator values without building a list

Tags: python, iterator

I would like to calculate unique values of an iterator, but without having to build a list first. Using a list, I would do for example:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

my_counts = Counter([sum(x) for x in combinations([1,2,3,4,5])],2)
```

But above, a list was made, and then `Counter` was applied. But is there a way to keep a running tally, so that the entire list does not need to stored in memory?

Comment: Oh, okay! What a simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just feed the `Counter` a generator expression instead of a `list`:

```
my_counts = Counter(sum(x) for x in combinations([1,2,3,4,5], 2))
```

or even shorter (but `map` only returns a generator in Python3):

```
my_counts = Counter(map(sum, combinations([1,2,3,4,5], 2)))
```

This will not build a list in memory first.